# How to use IKScannerDeviceView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics, scanning

I'm developing my first Objective C app; a simple program to scan an image and upload it to a server. So I was excited to see the **IKScannerDeviceView** in the library of Interface builder. However, whenever I drag it onto my sample app and run, the app freezes.

The [documentation on Apple's site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Quartz/Reference/IKScannerDeviceView_Class/Reference.html) has no examples.

What's the shortest distance to a running app that uses IKScannerDeviceView?

(I would much rather use this, than the [ancient TWAIN code](http://www.twain.org/mac.shtm), as was also suggested to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just put together a little app that scans one or more discrete pages and puts them together into a PDF file using IKScannerDeviceView. It's mostly "free" functionality assembled in Interface Builder. The class seems to be pretty quirky -- if you don't reset its post-processing app to nil, it opens Preview, and I can't actually get it to deliver scan results in-memory. But have a look at the code if you think it might be useful. [HG repo](https://bitbucket.org/davidreed/quickscan).

Comment: HG repo link is not working, if you have any example please share.

Comment: @IyyappanRavi This was seven years ago; the example would surely be out of date by now. I haven't written Mac code in many years.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, any idea to customize IKScannerDeviceView?